# Step back while debugging a C program in vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I feel like there should be an answer to this question somewhere, but even after half an hour of searching, I was unsuccessful. There are several documents about stepping back in Visual Studio, but I use vscode more often than Visual Studio and would like to know if this is possible in vscode, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about `Visual Studio IDE` or `Text Editor`.
If your question is about IDE then read this article from Microsoft
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/step-back-going-back-in-c-time/